# How to remove square brackets after displaying the list?

Tags: java, android, string, listview, arraylist

i declared ArrayList

`ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> usersList1234 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();` 
 and listview.

I set the ArrayList to ListView in the following way:

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(SearchFriendsActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, usersList1234);
        this.allUsers.setAdapter(adapter);
```

My list has quite a lot of elements (each element has three fields. this is how it looks:

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdLGQ.jpg)

[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8B3y.jpg)

When viewed on a virtual Android device, it looks like this ()

[Text, Text, Text]

[Text1, Text1, Text1]

[Text2, Text2, Text2]

Is there a way to remove these square brackets?

Comment: The bracket is there because your inner array list is being printed via the default toString method of array list. If you want custom views, use your own layout and make your own adapter which shows your connect according to how you want it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [ArrayAdapter source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java#ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource%28int%2Candroid.view.View%2Candroid.view.ViewGroup%2Cint%29), if your single object inside the List you send is not an instance of `CharSequence`, it just uses the `toString()` of that object.

And `ArrayList` `toString()` adds those `[]` for you, you need to pass `List<String>` and construct the strings yourself as you wish.

For each sub list you can do the appending yourself.